# Why i am unable to set z-index of div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a sample
http://jsbin.com/eqiti3
here we have three divs. Now, what i want to do is: on clicking of any div it should come on the top of other div then fade and then back to its original position. This is what i am using:

```
$(".box").click( function () {
    var zindex = $(this).css('z-index');     
  /* this too is not working
    $(this).css('z-index',14);  
    $(this).fadeTo ( 'slow', 0.5 ).fadeTo('slow', 1 )
    $(this).css('z-index',zindex);
  */

    $(this).css('z-index',14).fadeTo  ( 'slow', 0.5 ).fadeTo('slow', 1 ).css('z-index',zindex);

} );
```

provided `$(this).css('z-index',14)` this alone is capable of making the div to come over other divs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the callback

```
$(this).css('z-index',14)
    .fadeTo('slow', 0.5 )
    .fadeTo('slow', 1, function(){
        $(this).css('z-index',zindex);
    });
```

The [3rd parameter is a callback function](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/), it will run when the animation ends.

[Revision #3 on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/eqiti3/3).

Answer (score 5):

change your code to this:

```
$(".box").click( function () {
   var zindex = $(this).css('z-index');     

   $(this).css('z-index',14).fadeTo  ( 'slow', 0.5 ).fadeTo('slow', 1, function(){
       $(this).css('z-index',zindex);
   });
});
```

You can't chain the `.css()` method after `fadeTo()`, because those `fx` functions run asyncronously and therefore, `.css()` was executing immediately.

That's why all `fx` methods do offer callbacks which fire when finished.

See this in action: http://jsbin.com/eqiti3/2/edit

Comment: To clarify, you *are* setting the z-index of the items, it's just that you're setting it to 14, and then almost immediately back to what it was. What jAndy is doing is using the `fadeTo()` callback argument to make sure the animation is finished before setting the z-index back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Set background:'white'; it is solved for me